# Which data type should I use as the key for STL map?

Tags: c++, object, stl, codeblocks

I'm creating a program that reads some records from a .csv file and stores it in a map. My key is supposed to have two attributes, year and month. But in some cases, I'm asked to print the data of the entire year and in that case, I will not have the option to enter the month (ie month=0). So which data type should be best in this case? 
At first, I thought of integers but, it would not work if I'm asked to print the details of the entire year. I think probably using a user-defined type object would work, however, I'm a little confused about iterating the map.

Comment: "My key is supposed to have two attributes, year and month" so what is wrong with `struct my_date { int year; int month};` ?

Comment: "it would not work if I'm asked to print the details of the entire year" if you have problems with code, please include a [mcve]

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `Month` and `Year` are two independent keys, and that sometimes you are looking for non-unique results (e.g. year specified, month not specified). Simple solution is to store your records in `std::map<Year, std::map<Month, std::vector<Records> > my_data`; Then

- to get the records from the particular `Year`, you can iterate through the result of `my_data[Year("2020")]`
- to get the records from the particular `Month` (regardless the `Year`), `for (const auto& el: my_data) doSomething(el.second[Month("September")]);`
  = to get the results from the particular `Year` and `Month` `my_data[Year("2010")][Month("December")]`

Since C++20 you can use [year](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year) and [month](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/month) from the standard C++ library; Before that you can just define `Year` and `Month` structures and provide "less than" operator.